# Is dealloc guaranteed to be called on the same thread that created the object?

Tags: objective-c

Is `dealloc` guaranteed to be called on the same thread that created a `NSObject` instance? For example, if I call `[[MyFluffyBunny alloc] init]` on the main thread, is `dealloc` guaranteed to also be called on the main thread, or can it be called on any thread once `MyFluffyBunny` is no longer retained?

I see sporadic crashes in my app that points to that it's not guaranteed, but I've been unable to find any documentation confirming it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would it matter?

Comment: I have to call certain code in dealloc that's required to be executed on the main thread (3rd party API). I want to be sure of the above before I add a thread check and a dispatch_sync call

Comment: Why worry about it? Use `dspatch_sync` and ensure it works no matter what. It's it already on the main thread, it's basically a no-op.

Comment: The docs for `dispatch_sync` says it causes a dead-lock if used on the same queue as it's passed. I'm not too worried, I just wanted to be somewhat certain of the above first.

Comment: Or just use  `dispatch_async`...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The object is deallocated on whatever thread releases the last strong reference to it. That is, whatever thread calls `-release` the final time. It is actually *during* that `-release` call that the object is deallocated.

The [documentation for the `-release` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/release) in the `NSObject` protocol says:

> Decrements the receiver’s reference count. … The receiver is sent a `dealloc` message when its reference count reaches 0.

The Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide: Practical Memory Management article includes this among the [reasons to not use `-dealloc` to manage scarce resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW13):

> 3. Cleanup logic being executed on the wrong thread.
>
>    If an object is autoreleased at an unexpected time, it will be deallocated on whatever thread’s autorelease pool block it happens to be in. This can easily be fatal for resources that should only be touched from one thread.

Comment: Just to confirm - I assume you mean that the object is _deallocated_ during the call to `release`? If the object wasn't released during a call to `release`, I'd be very concerned.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such guarantee and, in fact, it makes for some subtle bugs when using KVO (and bindings on OS X).

You can see it in action fairly easily by creating an object that logs `[NSThread currentThread]` during `init` and `dealloc`, then running code such as:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    Testing *testing = [[Testing alloc] init];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Use testing in background: %@", testing);
    });
    testing = nil;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a line in the documentation that says anything about this, but here are some points of logic:

- If you can't find a guarantee somewhere, assume it doesn't exist. *(It sounds like you're aware of this already, and are hoping beyond hope that somebody else can point you to something that gives you the answer you want)*
- That requirement cannot be possible because you can construct something on a thread, then end that thread, then have the last reference go out of scope somewhere else in some other thread. It wouldn't be possible at this point to `dealloc` on the old thread because it no longer exists.