# Over-released object iOS app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, automatic-ref-counting

My app is crashing with the last message in the device console:

> objc[5105]: Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x10801ec00) of class UIPageViewController. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.

Randomly app also crashed with the same error message but `UINavigationController` instead of `UIPageViewController`. A bug is reproducible on the simulator and physical devices (iOS 11.2.5).

Profiling with "Zombie" template in Instruments did not give any valuable information. I found that outdated guide useful:
http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2007/10/instruments-on-leopard-how-to-debug-those-random-crashes-in-your-cocoa-app/

---

My answer might not fix your issue but I hope it will help to track it. Additionally, I'll appreciate if someone explains why ARC fired on a different thread.

Comment: What are you doing when it's crashing? Are you programmatically dismissing a view by any chance. It's going to be impossible to diagnose a crash without details about what you were doing when it crashed and/or the salient details of the crash (e.g. the stack trace, etc.).

Comment: In contemporary versions of Xcode there is a "Main Thread Checker" option on the scheme's "Diagnostics" options. Do you have this turned on?

Comment: If the "Main Thread Checker" doesn't solve the problem, I'd suggest you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include that in your question.

Comment: I'm not able to create MCVE, it happens only in (complex) app I'm working on. "Main Thread Checker" is on and does not complain about anything. I know where last reference to the array holding references to the view controllers is removed, and I did check that it happens on main thread. Problem is that `dealloc` is not called on main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By subclassing `UIPageViewController` and setting breakpoint in it's `dealloc` I found that it's not executed on the main thread.

**don't do this in production - only play around when debugging**

Synchronously removing its view from view hierarchy on the main thread did fix the issue. I have no view controller container responsible for that:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    });
}
```

However it was not even about the view, while just delaying execution was enough to fix the crash, and the view will be cleaned together with its superview.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", self);
    });
}
```

View controllers were stored in the array, and I knew that when this array was destroyed, view controllers are as well. I checked on which thread object holding the only one reference to this array is destroyed, and it is main thread. ARC should release objects on same thread where the last reference to the object was removed, but that is not the case in my app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800112

---

**How did I fix my issue:**
I don't why it was so. I did not search for a reason anymore when I found that issue will also disappear when **I manually remove reference to the array, right before removing the last reference to its owner.**

Comment: What you're doing here is very problematic. Note the message in the first post that says _... or is in the process of deallocation._ You're code (specifically the code block that references `self`) is causing a retain of `self` during `dealloc`. You can't do that—ever. `dealloc` executes when the object has been released and any attempt to retain the object again will cause unexpected and unpredictable havoc.

Comment: @JamesBucanek thanks for your reply. I agree with you so I did additionally clarify what was the correct solution.